# Determine the number of digits in $(2^{120})(5^{125})$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

**Determine the number of digits in $(2^{120})(5^{125})$.**

This is a bonus question I found in a Grade 12 math textbook, and I'm curious on how to solve it. What I find strange is that this question is in the  "Power Functions" section of "Polynomial Functions"; yet, this seems to have little to do with functions.

Any ideas as to how to solve this? I have tried to, but can't find a solution without a computer or calculator.

Comment: Do you know about logarithm?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Observe that 
$$2^{120}5^{125}=2^{120}5^{120}5^5=10^{120}\cdot3125$$
So the number is $3125$ followed by $120$ zeroes.

Answer (score 2):

The base-$10$ logarithm of $2$ is $0.30103$, so the base-$10$ logarithm of $5$ is $0.69897$ (at least four exact decimal digits). So the base-$10$ logarithm of $2^{120}\cdot 5^{125}$ is
$$120\cdot0.30103+125\cdot0.69897=123.49485$$
Thus the number has 124 digits.

Of course, noticing that the number is also $5^5\cdot10^{120}$ is faster and gives the exact result.